# Insert into database with php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, mamp, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data into my database, but it doesnt work, i get no errors. I guess something is wrong with my php code, but i tried some solutions on web that worked for some other people, but not for me.

my html code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>

<title>Neues Projekt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

    <head>
        <h1>Neues Projekt anlegen</h1>
    </head>

    <body>
<form action="php_skript.php" method="post">    
  <p>Name des Projekts:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <p>Ort des Projekts:</p>
  <input type="text" name="ort">
  <p>Straße des Projekts:</p>  
  <input type="text" name="strasse">
  <p>Projektleiter:</p> 
  <input type="text" name="projektleiter">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  Bilder hinzufügen:
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="image_data" multiple>
          </form>


      </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

and here my php code:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'projekte_db';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$ort=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['ort']);
$strasse=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['strasse']);
$projektleiter=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['projektleiter']);

$mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);


if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Projekt (name,ort,straße,projektleiter) VALUES ('$name','$ort','$strasse','$projektleiter')");

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Post your DB schema. And there should be errors. Check server logs

Comment: `var_dump()` your $_POST variables to make sure they are being sent correctly

Comment: straße 5th character is special character or what ?

Comment: You check for connection errors (good) but them assume that insertion cannot fail. But the main problem is that you use `$mysqli` before you define it and PHP doesn't warn you. That means that you haven't configured PHP to display error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$mysqli` variable need to comes before:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db); //put here

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$ort=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['ort']);
$strasse=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['strasse']);
$projektleiter=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['projektleiter']);

//$mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db); remove here
```

Also, I suggest you to use parameterized queries, it's more safe.

Comment: actually now it works, i guess the problem was because of the german letter "ß" in "straße" and that my $mysqli didnt came before thank you for that felippe and  @Dr Manish Joshi

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inserting data try to use prepared statements

```
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'projekte_db';
$host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$ort=$_POST['ort'];
$strasse=$_POST['strasse'];
$projektleiter=$_POST['projektleiter'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `Projekt` (`name`,`ort`,`straße`,`projektleiter`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    /* use s for strings, i for integer,d for double, b for blob */
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name,$ort,$strasse,$projektleiter);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: thanks for that one!

Comment: hope it helped @Korken55

Comment: it actually worked before, but i guess this solution is a better and maybe safer way? to do it. @Peter Darmis

Comment: @Korken55 prepared statements are more secure by default.